# MariaDB punto dentro de polígono

Tags: sql, mariadb

Estoy intentando que esto devuelva "true"

```sql
SELECT CONTAINS(
    GeomFromText('Polygon((41.532009 1.681379,41.531936 1.681966,41.531143 1.681799,41.531211 1.681214))'),
    PointFromText('Point(41.532009 1.681379)')
) AS is_inside;
```

Comment: ¿Que datos tienes en tu base de datos? ¿Cuáles son los campos que tienes en las tablas?

Comment: ¿Miraste alguna de las respuestas que te ofrecimos?

Answer (score 1):

¿Qué versión de MariaDB estás usando?

Tal y como puedes ver en la documentación (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/st-contains/) debes usar `ST_CONTAINS` si quieres una comprobación geométrica completa y no la implementación heredada de MySQL (basada en rectángulos delimitadores de forma).

Por otro lado, quizá debieras usar siempre formas geométricas y mezclarlas con puntos. Mira el ejemplo:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/st-contains/

```
SET @g1 = ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((175 150, 20 40, 50 60, 125 100, 175 150))');

SET @g2 = ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(174 149)');

SELECT ST_CONTAINS(@g1,@g2);
+----------------------+
| ST_CONTAINS(@g1,@g2) |
+----------------------+
|                    1 |
+----------------------+
```

Por último, sólo dispongo de Percona y MySQL original para hacer las pruebas, por lo que no puedo probar las funciones `ST_*` con exactitud para decirte si el hecho de no cerrar correctamente una forma geométrica afecta al resultado (por no estar comparando sólo el rectángulo que contiene la forma).

Si es así (si debe ser una forma cerrada), prueba a cerrar la forma poniendo la misma coordenada inicial como final.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la ayuda oficial de MariaDB:

Si cualquier argumento en la creación de un polígono no representa un WKB, es decir, que no está cerrado por ejemplo, la instrucción devuelve `NULL`.

**En tu código:**

`GeomFromText('Polygon((41.532009 1.681379,41.531936 1.681966,41.531143 1.681799,41.531211 1.681214))')` te estaría faltando **cerrar el polígono** repitiendo la primera coordenada.

Debería ser así:

`GeomFromText('Polygon((41.532009 1.681379,41.531936 1.681966,41.531143 1.681799,41.531211 1.681214, 41.532009 1.681379))')`

De lo contrario al buscar un punto en un objeto nulo nunca va a dar true.

Answer (score 0):

En MySQL 5.7 me funciona de esta manera:

```
SELECT CONTAINS(
    GeomFromText('Polygon((41.532009 1.681379,41.531936 1.681966,41.531143 1.681799,41.531211 1.681214, 41.532009 1.681379))'),
    PointFromText('Point(41.532009 1.681379)')
) AS is_inside;
```

El inicio y el fin de tu polígono siempre tiene que ser igual como indico arriba.
En versiones de MySQL 5.5 y 5.6 no necesitaban cerrarse. Seguramente ocurre lo mismo en MariaDB.

El resultado de esta consulta es 1.